# Correct try-catch syntax?

Tags: c#

If I want to preserve the stack trace and I have this catch block...

```
try
{
    //Cause exception here...
}
catch (CustomException customEx)
{
    //Handle custom exception here...
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

Will the above catch (without parameter) rethrow the exception?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear. Your actual question seems to be *"Does a `catch(SpecificException)` fall through to the general `catch`?"*, to which the answer is "no".

If by "the" exception you mean "any other exception than `CustomException`", then yes, they will be rethrown.

If you want to rethrow the latter too, you'll also need a `throw` in the `catch(CustomException customex)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `try-catch-finally`

> A common usage of catch and finally together is to obtain and use resources in a try block, deal with exceptional circumstances in a catch block, and release the resources in the finally block.
>   For more information and examples on re-throwing exceptions, see try-catch and Throwing Exceptions. For more information about the finally block, see try-finally.

for more details see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989.aspx